# Consistent figure sizes with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to make figures with gnuplot that will be included in a latex document. I want all figures to have the same dimensions and font size. To achieve it I found that I should specify the size of the figure in advance, which I do as such:

```
set terminal postscript eps size 3.4004,2.104 enhanced color
```

However, the resulting .eps figures have a lot of whitespace around them so I use the [fixbb](http://www.gnuplot.info/scripts/files/fixbb) script to remove all unnecessary space. This changes the final size of the figure as well, which wouldn't be a problem as long as it is consistent. However, the amount of whitespace seems to vary from figure to figure, so my final figures have all different sizes.
This seems especially a problem with 3D plots.

Is there a way to make the size consistent while removing all unnecessary white space? In matplotlib there is the `plt.tight_layout()` command which does exactly that.

Comment: No, there isn't an equivalent command in gnuplot. You'll have scale the plot manually with `set size` and shift its origin with `set origin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by fixing the size of the figure you refer to the rectangle within which the data is plotted, you can set the margins manually. What I usually do for figures I put on my papers is use the `epslatex` terminal with the desired size and font, then set the margins, and then compile to pdf followed by a cropping to remove the white space. Example

```
set term epslatex color size 3.5,2.5 font 6
set output "gnuplot.eps"

set lmargin at screen 0.2
set rmargin at screen 0.98
set tmargin at screen 0.98
set bmargin at screen 0.1

plot sin(x) title '$\sin (x)$'
```

I embed this into a .tex file (which I call `plot.tex`):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[papersize={100cm,100cm}]{geometry}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage[mathcal]{euscript}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\include{gnuplot}

\end{document}
```

And run the following:

```
pdflatex plot.tex
pdfcrop plot.pdf
```

You will have a `plot-crop.pdf` with no white space around. Using different modifications of the above you can very precisely modify the size of your graph.

[image]

Finally, note that the `epslatex` terminal also allows the `standalone` option to avoid needing an external latex document to wrap your graph.